# useEffect cleanup function on conditions

Tags: reactjs

Do we need to do any cleanup when we execute a useEffect hook to run on a condition? If we provide an if statement and it's executed correctly do we just move on or is there anything else required? I am just thinking in perspective or performance etc.

```
useEffect(() => { 
if (condition) { 
runThisFunction()
  }
}, [condition]);
```

Comment: What do you want to cleanup ?

Comment: What does runThisFunction do? If it does something that needs to be cleaned up, you should return a cleanup function, but you'll only need to return it in the `if` case. If it doesn't do anything that needs to be cleaned up then... you don't need to clean up.

Comment: In this particular instance, we check that when the component mounts and condition is true we post a request to the backend.

Comment: Then no in your case there's nothing to clean up. Generally you only need to do cleanup if you subscribed to something and need to unsubscribe on unmount or something along those lines. Or more generally, if the effect mutated something that you need to change back to the original value when it unmounts. Not the case here.